# htaccess redirect 301 with or without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, match

I have some urls looking like this:

```
redirect 301 /some/old/url/ http://example.com/url
redirect 301 /some/old/test/ http://example.com/test
```

What I do want is kind of like this:

```
redirect 301 /some/old/[word-match-with-or-without-trailing-slash] http://example.com/[same-word-without-trailing slash]
```

How do I do this? The problems:

1. Match both with or without slash.
2. Keep the match without slash for later use (see next).
3. Put the match witout slash at the end of the line.

**Update**

It seems like I could do something like this (untested):

```
redirect 301 /some/old/(.*) http://example.com/$1
```

But then how can I remove the possible trailing slash in `$1`?

Comment: See [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect): "Additional path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the target URL."

Comment: @OlafDietsche Alright! I updated my question with an update with a possible half solution. If it's there by `$1`, how can I remove the possible ending slash to not use it in the new url?

Comment: You cannot with `Redirect`. For more elaborate modifications, you need `RedirectMatch` or even `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect to remove the trailing slash ,you can use :

```
RedirectMatch ^/some/old/(.*?)/?$ http://example.com/$1
```

Comment: It seems to work but the status is 302. Is it possible to use status 301, permanent redirect?

Comment: 302 is the default status. You can add 301 or permanent as the first argument of RedirectMatch

Comment: @JensTörnell Never test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!